# Not sure where to find limits for Google Places Api free use

Tags: mobile, google-places-api

How much will I pay per month for 10k dau for an average geo location mobile game using google places (for POI)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to pricing and plans comparison [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details) , but they are stated in requests so you need to calculate average request per user for your app and convert it to your 10k DAU